# push webclip to an iOS device with iPCU profile

Tags: ios, mdm

I want to push a webclip to an iOS device with iPCU profile wirelessly without knowing the device context? What are the steps to be followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) iPCU is used to push configuration profiles (including webclips) only through USB connectio

b) If you want to do this wirelessly, you can either do this:

- OTA (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/ConfigurationProfileExamples/ConfigurationProfileExamples.html)
- MDM (You need to sign up for Apple Enterprise Developer program to access the official document. And here is [unofficial](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf))

c) Is your question a programming question at all or are you looking for existing solution which does that

d) What is device context?

Comment: On clicking of link, I have to create webclip payload with dynamic url in server side code and then push the webclip to the device.

Comment: @Shab: In such case, you don't need even OTA. All you need to do is to create a page which dynamically creates configuration profile (the format is specified here - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) and set application/x-apple-aspen-config as MIME type

Comment: yes. I did the same. Created the payload dynamically, set the mime type of the response as application/x-apple-aspen-config and sent the payload in response. but getting error as " Safari could not install the profile due to unknown errors" ..

Comment: Most likely there are some errors in your profile. Check console log of your device while installation to see what is the problem.

Comment: the same configuration, when sent as response to ota.mobile config installed the webclip. but when i tried without OTA, it does not work.

Comment: You should look at console log to see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the iPCU app on AppStore. You can create Web Clips among other profiles such as LDAP, VPN, etc and deploy them on either your own device or others via FTP, Email, or Dropbox.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipcu/id513585146?mt=8